# Use PHP alternate syntax with WAMP

Tags: php, codeigniter, syntax, wamp

Is it possible to use PHP alternate syntax (as described in the CodeIgniter user guide), on WAMP?

Comment: You should clarify what kind of alternate syntax exactly you're talking about. Control structures? Short open tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be entirely PHP controlled, not by WAMPServer or the environment in which you are running.

You need to find your php.ini file and set `short_open_tag = 1`, although this should already be set.

I know some installs of PHP can put php.ini in random places. To find out the file location, simply call `phpinfo();` in any php file. Relatively near the top, you should find the location of the loaded php.ini file.

I hope this can be of help to you.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is, i don't believe alternate syntax is environment dependent as it's a part of the language. This is not the same as PHP shorttags, the two are independent of each other.

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: Does it have to be enables in some way? I am using the most recent WAMP build (WampServer 2.0i).

Comment: I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation that suggests that this feature needs to be enabled, or even *can be* enabled/disabled. I don't have wamp handy so I can't test, but I'm sure I've used it on wamp before without problems. have you tested it?

Answer (score 0):

CI has an option in application/config.php to dynamically re-write

not sure what kind of performance impact this causes but i certainly use i